# Convert times created by Javascript's getTime() method to ruby Time objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Javascript's `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970.

How do I convert the output of `getTime()` to a Ruby Time object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Time.at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251) method, and divide the JavaScript timestamp value by 1000, since the at method, uses seconds instead of milliseconds, for example:

```
jsTime = 1252268867928
print Time.at(jsTime/1000)
# Sun Sep 06 20:27:47 +0000 2009
```