# What the date? Stuck in the year 45,338 using Elasticsearch and Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Elasticsearch and Tire in my Rails4 application and am lost with the whole date thing.

Having created a facet:

```
facet('timeline') { date   :created_at, :interval => 'day' }
```

This looked fine until I grab the data and end up with:

```
= @device.facets["timeline"]
> {"_type"=>"date_histogram", "entries"=>[{"time"=>1361232000000, "count"=>1}, {"time"=>1361318400000, "count"=>14}, {"time"=>1361404800000, "count"=>1}
```

I tried formatting the date in the mappings but that's not right:

```
indexes :created_at, type: 'date', :date_formats => 'basic_date'
```

I've read through the docs about yoda time etc. but I don't know how to format this into something reasonable. Currently converting this in Ruby leaves me with a time of:

```
45338-06-13 01:00:00 +0100 :(
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/

Comment: Can you post what you are sending to elasticsearch as an indexed document. Also post your mapping from the [Get mapping api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to divide the timestamp returned by Elasticsearch by 1000, since it uses a different timestamp representation:

```
Time.at( 1361232000000 / 1000 )
```

---

See this answer on StackOverflow: [Convert times created by Javascript's getTime() method to ruby Time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386626/convert-times-created-by-javascripts-gettime-method-to-ruby-time-objects)

Comment: Thanks, thought it was something stupidly simple. Tire's fantastic btw, good work :)